# String Concatenation Error in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am having some trouble concating 2 strings. Here is what I am doing :

```
    Dim bound1 As String
    Dim bound2 As String

    bound1 = "E6:E" & 6 + tTest_Threshold
    bound2 = "E" & 6 + index1 & ":E" & 6 + index2

    Worksheets(chipSheet1).Cells(currIteration + 7, 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=TTEST(" & bound1 & "," & bound2 & ",2,1)"
```

However, it is printing : `=TTEST('E6':'E12','E8':'E14',2,1)`

I donot understand, why `"'"` is printed in the Excel formula. Any idea what I am doing wrong in the code ?

Thanks

Comment: Try brackets around (6 + tTest_Threshold), (6 + index1) and (6 + index2), perhaps?

Comment: I am trying now, But I have never used "()" in string concatenation. Does it remove the "'" from the formula, you think ?

Comment: No, It didn't. It is still printing the "'" in the formula. I donot know why..

Comment: OK, sorry.  I guessed that it might be doing `"E6:E" & 6` (giving "E6:E6"), and then trying to add an integer to that, causing confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
 Worksheets(chipSheet1).Cells(currIteration + 7, 5).Formula = "=TTEST(" & bound1 & "," & bound2 & ",2,1)"
```

instead of

```
Worksheets(chipSheet1).Cells(currIteration + 7, 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=TTEST(" & bound1 & "," & bound2 & ",2,1)"
```

Answer (score 3):

I suspect its because you're assigning to the `FormulaR1C1` property, which expects a different notation pattern that the one you're using. Try filling the `Formula` property instead.

To quote [this MSDN forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/07417609-c70c-43d5-b495-d8db0f4e676c/):

> Formula returns the formula in A1 notation, FormulaR1C1 returns the
>   formula in R1C1 notation.
>
> By default, Excel uses the A1 reference style, which refers to columns
>   with letters (A through IV, for a total of 256 columns) and refers to
>   rows with numbers (1 through 65536). These letters and numbers are
>   called row and column headings. To refer to a cell, enter the column
>   letter followed by the row number. For example, D50 refers to the cell
>   at the intersection of column D and row 50.
>
> In the R1C1 reference style, both the rows and the columns on the
>   worksheet are numbered. In the R1C1 style, Excel indicates the
>   location of a cell with an "R" followed by a row number and a "C"
>   followed by a column number. For example, the absolute cell reference
>   R1C1 is equivalent to the absolute reference $A$1 in A1 reference
>   style.